# CDI doesn't work when ejb inject implementation define in war of same ear

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, ear

I have an EAR file containing multiple ejb-jar and war. In an ejb-jar, I inject multiple implementations of an interface like this :

```
@Inject
@Any
private Instance<ConfigurationProviderLocal> providerEjb;
```

An implementation of this interface is defined in a war. This implementation deploys fine.

In the glassfish v3.1 log I see:

> Infos: Portable JNDI names for EJB FormConfigurationProviderBean : 
>   [java:global/com.dialog.edialog_eservices_ear_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/checkout-form-1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   /FormConfigurationProviderBean,
>   java:global/com.dialog.edialog_eservices_ear_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/checkout-form-1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   /FormConfigurationProviderBean!com.dialog.sbsm.talisker.core.config.api.ConfigurationProviderLocal]

But in the iteration of my implementations:

```
for (ConfigurationProviderLocal provider : providerEjb) {
            [...]
        }
```

The implementation `FormConfigurationProviderBean` is never iterated. I have no message in log that could explain this.

Also, when I deploy the war in stand alone (not inside ear, with dependencies embedded inside it), the injection work correctly.

Is CDI supported when implementation is defined inside a war? Is there a classloader issue?

Comment: It seems it's a classloader issue : when i "export" my implemntation in another ejb-jar and i declare it as depdency of my war (scope provided) et and the ear(scope compile), all works perfectly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *should* work, provided that the setup is correct (which probably is the case).

I had a similar issue in the JBoss World (on AS 6) where different artifacts in an EAR could not see each other. I solved it by re-configuring the JBoss classloading-mechanism, but this was plain (and proprietary) JBoss stuff.

What I would do as a first debug step: Query the [BeanManager](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e4939) about what beans are really around. This might give you a hint. A small [CDI-extension](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html) which dumps the initial bean processing could be helpful as well.

If it still looks like a CL-issue you might find configuration options for that in the Glassfish documentations. Probably worthwhile to check with the GlassFish developers if that is a known problem / issue...

Comment: Thanks for the link. I don't know if i will use them to solve this issue, as i "workaround" it by using an ejb-jar to store my ejb. I didn't know BeanMamaner end CDI-extension : i'll bookmark it.